# Mi programa se detiene cuando ejecuto una función

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que está en un JFrame, cuando ejecuto la función `Parender();` con el botón `aprender`, el programa se detiene y no hace más nada.

```
package neurona2.org;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Funciona extends JFrame {

private JLabel lx1, lx2, ly1, cambio, x1l, x2l, r1;
private JTextField textx1, textx2, texty1, textx1a, textx2a, texty1a, textx1b, textx2b, texty1b, textx1c, textx2c,
        texty1c, t1, t2;
public double x1, x1a, x1b, x1c, x2, x2a, x2b, x2c, y1, y1a, y1b, y1c;

private JButton button1, aceptar, aprender;

double w1 = new Random().nextDouble();
double w2 = new Random().nextDouble();
double umbral = new Random().nextDouble();
double yr = 0;
double error = 0;
double wx = 0;
int i = 0;

double tv[][] = {{ x1, x2, y1 }, { x1a, x2a, y1a }, { x1b, x2b, y1b }, { x1c, x2c, y1c } };

public Funciona() {
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(450, 450);
    this.setTitle("Aprendizaje");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Instanciando Cuadros de Texto

    lx1 = new JLabel("X1");
    this.add(lx1);
    lx1.setBounds(25, 15, 25, 20);

    textx1 = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1);
    textx1.setBounds(25, 30, 30, 30);

    lx2 = new JLabel("X2");
    this.add(lx2);
    lx2.setBounds(75, 15, 25, 20);

    textx2 = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2);
    textx2.setBounds(75, 30, 30, 30);

    ly1 = new JLabel("Y");
    this.add(ly1);
    ly1.setBounds(125, 10, 25, 30);

    texty1 = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1);
    texty1.setBounds(125, 30, 30, 30);

    textx1a = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1a);
    textx1a.setBounds(25, 90, 30, 30);

    textx2a = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2a);
    textx2a.setBounds(75, 90, 30, 30);

    texty1a = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1a);
    texty1a.setBounds(125, 90, 30, 30);

    textx1b = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1b);
    textx1b.setBounds(25, 145, 30, 30);

    textx2b = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2b);
    textx2b.setBounds(75, 145, 30, 30);

    texty1b = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1b);
    texty1b.setBounds(125, 145, 30, 30);

    textx1c = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx1c);
    textx1c.setBounds(25, 195, 30, 30);

    textx2c = new JTextField();
    this.add(textx2c);
    textx2c.setBounds(75, 195, 30, 30);

    texty1c = new JTextField();
    this.add(texty1c);
    texty1c.setBounds(125, 195, 30, 30);

    cambio = new JLabel();
    this.add(cambio);
    cambio.setBounds(200, 320, 200, 30);

    t1 = new JTextField();
    this.add(t1);
    t1.setBounds(200, 60, 40, 35);

    x1l = new JLabel("X1");
    this.add(x1l);
    x1l.setBounds(200, 30, 40, 35);

    t2 = new JTextField();
    this.add(t2);
    t2.setBounds(250, 60, 40, 35);

    x2l = new JLabel("X2");
    this.add(x2l);
    x2l.setBounds(250, 30, 40, 35);

    r1 = new JLabel("Resultado");
    this.add(r1);
    r1.setBounds(350, 50, 150, 35);


        // Fin cuadros de texto

        // Botones

        button1 = new JButton("Aceptar");
        this.add(button1);
        button1.setBounds(25, 300, 100, 20);

        aceptar = new JButton("Aceptar");
        this.add(aceptar);
        aceptar.setBounds(205, 150, 100, 35);

        aprender = new JButton("Entrenar");
        this.add(aprender); 
        aprender.setBounds(200, 250, 100, 20);


        //Fin botones

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                double x1 = Double.parseDouble(textx1.getText());
                double x1a = Double.parseDouble(textx1a.getText());
                double x1b = Double.parseDouble(textx1b.getText());
                double x1c = Double.parseDouble(textx1c.getText());
                double x2 = Double.parseDouble(textx2.getText());
                double x2a = Double.parseDouble(textx2a.getText());
                double x2b = Double.parseDouble(textx2b.getText());
                double x2c = Double.parseDouble(textx2c.getText());
                double y1 = Double.parseDouble(texty1.getText());
                double y1a = Double.parseDouble(texty1a.getText());
                double y1b = Double.parseDouble(texty1b.getText());
                double y1c = Double.parseDouble(texty1c.getText());
                cambio.setText("Valores aprendidos");


            }
        });

        aprender.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Aprender();
            }
        });


    }
    public void Aprender() {

        while (i < tv.length) {
            wx = (tv[i][0] * w1) + (tv[i][1] * w2) - umbral;
            yr = (wx == umbral) ? 1 : -1;
            if (yr == tv[i][2]) {
                i++;
            } else {
                error = tv[i][2] - wx;
                w1 = w1 + error * tv[i][0];
                w2 = w2 + error * tv[i][1];
                if (umbral < 0) {
                    umbral = (umbral + error) * -1;
                } else {
                    umbral = umbral + error;
                }
                i = 0;
            } // Final Else
        } // Final While

    }// Final funcion

}
```

Comment: Juan, aporta más datos a tus preguntas, en este caso el error que obtienes, revisa [ask] para obtener información de como realizar buenas preguntas y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas que te ayuden a solucionar tu problema!, saludos!

Comment: El método Parender() no existe, imagino te refieres a Aprender(). Trata de revisar tu pregunta nuevamente.

Comment: @Jorgesys la funcion Aprender(), lo siento. Es la funcion que se ejecuta con el boton aprender.

Comment: Mete una traza de salida de consola antes de `// Final While`, apuesto a que se queda indefinidamente en el bucle debido a que `i` nunca se incrementa la suficiente.

Comment: @JuanPimentel efectivamente como dice Jose D. Jurado, el incrementar la variable **i** de forma tan aleatoria tiene como consecuencia un bucle infinito o si no es infinito tardará mucho en realizarlo.